# Deserialize object in C# console application

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I serialize object with JavaScriptSerializer class, set argument for Console App and then deserialize

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    public decimal LoanAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal LoanRate { get; set; }
    public decimal LoanTerm { get; set; }
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Serialize:

```
MyModel _model = new MyModel()
{
    FullName = "test_FullName",
    LoanID = 11110,
    LoanAmount = 4000
};


var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(_model, sb);
```

Call C# Console application:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = @"...exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = sb.ToString();

using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Deserialize:

```
string input = args[0];
var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(input);
```

If I comment  'FullName = "test_FullName"' deserialization works, but in other case it returns error: **Invalid JSON primitive: test_FullName**

Comment: How does your input exactly look like?

Comment: Here is input {LoanID:11110,LoanAmount:4000,LoanRate:17,LoanTerm:10,PIN:null,FullName:test_FullName}

Comment: Sorry here must be MyModel,I have already edit

Answer (score 0):

The input is incorrect. The value for FullName must be enclosed in double quotes eg:

{"FullName":"test_FullName","LoanID":11110,"LoanAmount":4000}

Comment: Input parameter is taken from StringBuilder sb, shown on second code sniper